# C# Trying to subscribe to an event in Unity

Tags: c#, events, unity-game-engine, kinect

I'm using the Kinect v2 with Unity3D.
A class BodyFramReader has an event Framearrived that I wish to subscribe to.
Heres my code so far..

```
    void Start()
    {
        man.kman._BodyReader.FrameArrived  += this.FrameIn;
    }

    void FrameIn(BodyFrameReader sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs a)
    {
        // Do something useful here.
    }
```

I get the following error in visual studio.
[image]
It seems my delegate method is not right. If that is the problem how do I find the right parameters? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your `sender` parameter doesn't match the parameter in [`EventHandler<TEventArgs>`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/db0etb8x) - it should be of type `object`:

```
void FrameIn(object sender, BodyFrameArrivedEventArgs e)
```

If you need the sender as a `BodyFrameReader`, you can cast to it within the method.